# Asp.net Custom Web hook

Tags: c#, asp.net, webhooks

I am trying to learn webhooks, my requirement needs to have a publisher which can publish some data and all its subscriber will receive webhook notification.
Here my requirement i needs to have both publisher and receiver in local host.

I am trying out using the following post.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2015/09/15/sending-webhooks-with-asp-net-webhooks-preview.aspx

How ever when i call the subscribe method it fails. Please advice, whether i am doing any thing wrong.

```
function subscribe() {
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/api/webhooks/registrations",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        WebHookUri: "http://localhost:59927/api/webhooks/incoming/custom",
        Secret: "12345678901234567890123456789012",
        Description: "My first WebHook!"
    }),
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, status) { alert(status); },
    failure: function(errMsg) { alert(errMsg); }
});
return false;
```

}

This is the error message when i call subscribe method.

"Message":"WebHook verification failed. Please ensure that the WebHook URI is valid and that the endpoint
 is accessible. Error encountered: NotFound","ExceptionMessage":"WebHook verification failed. Please
 ensure that the WebHook URI is valid and that the endpoint is accessible. Error encountered: NotFound"
,"ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException"

and this is my WebApiConfig.cs file

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Load Web API controllers 
        config.InitializeCustomWebHooks();
        config.InitializeCustomWebHooksApis();
        config.InitializeReceiveCustomWebHooks();
    }
}
```

and Global.asax file

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);            
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the same problem (using the latest version (RC1) of the WebHooks packages).

I tracked it down using the source code on GitHub. When you register a WebHook the registration endpoint sends a Get request to the WebHook url (htp://host/api/webhooks/incoming/custom) to check whether it is a valid url or not. In my case the endpoint was not found due to the controller not being present.

I've managed to solve it by making sure the assembly that contains the `WebHookReceiversController` that provides the `api/webhooks/incoming` endpoint is loaded. Change your code to this:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Make sure the assembly Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers is loaded
        var controllerType = typeof (WebHookReceiversController);

        // Web API configuration and services

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        // Load Web API controllers 
        config.InitializeCustomWebHooks();
        config.InitializeCustomWebHooksApis();
        config.InitializeReceiveCustomWebHooks();

        config.EnsureInitialized();

        var webhookRoutes = config.Routes;
        ; // Set breakpoint here and inspect the variable above, you should see the custom incoming webhook route listened.
    }
}
```

Note: the line

```
var controllerType = typeof (WebHookReceiversController);
```

is added.

If that assembly is not loaded before the routes are mapped the controller is not discovered and therefore not included in the routes known to the api, hence the NotFound error.

A complete end-to-end project using self hosted api projects can be found here:
https://github.com/Expecho/WebHooks-PoC

Comment: @BaqerNaqvi If you inspect all the routes in `config.Routes`, does it show your incoming endpoint?

Comment: No, I placed a debug point before config.InitializeReceiveCustomWebHooks() in WebApiConfig and inspected config.Routes by hovering on config.Routes.MapHttpRoute... code and it does not include api/webhooks/incoming/custom rather in contains two entries one that is default and the second one is empty.

Comment: You should set a breakpoint after all the initializations. What happens then? Can you post your code somewhere?

Comment: @BaqerNaqvi can you take a look at my pull request? Looks like I missed the `EnsureInitialized` call

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the WebHookURI property points to your actual server by setting the HTTP port to the correct value, for example

http://localhost:YOURPORTVALUE/api/webhooks/incoming/custom

http://localhost:12345/

You might also be missing the following line:

```
        config.InitializeCustomWebHooksAzureStorage();
```

in your WebApiConfig.cs

We just use the local Development Storage so set the MS_AzureStoreConnectionString connection string

Have a Look at the following

The support for sending WebHooks is provided by the following Nuget packages:

Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Custom: This package provides the core functionality for adding WebHook support to your ASP.NET project. The functionality enables users to register WebHooks using a simple pub/sub model and for your code to send WebHooks to receivers with matching WebHook registrations.

Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Custom.AzureStorage This package provides optional support for persisting WebHook registrations in Microsoft Azure Table Storage.

Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Custom.SqlStorage This package provides optional support for persisting WebHook registrations in SQL. See Updates to Microsoft ASP.NET WebHooks Preview for a description of how to use it.

Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Custom.Mvc This package exposes optional helpers for accessing WebHooks functionality from within ASP.NET MVC Controllers. The helpers assist in providing WebHook registration through MVC controllers as well as creating event notification to be sent to WebHook registrants.

Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Custom.Api This package contains an  optional set of ASP.NET Web API Controllers for managing filters and registrations through a REST-style interface.

a great place to start would be here

https://github.com/aspnet/WebHooks/tree/master/samples

Answer (score 0):

your startup looks different from the article:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
        {
            // Web API configuration and services

            // Web API routes
            config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
                defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );

            // Load Web API controllers and Azure Storage store
            config.InitializeCustomWebHooks();
            config.InitializeCustomWebHooksAzureStorage();
            config.InitializeCustomWebHooksApis();
            config.InitializeReceiveCustomWebHooks();
        }
    }
}
```

particularly look at this line:

```
config.InitializeCustomWebHooksAzureStorage();
```

you don't have any storage setup.  hopefully this helps someone.

cheers

Answer (score -3):

In case someone still has the problems with that example (even after one year!), here is package that fixed my pain:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Custom -Pre
```

It's a latest version of receiver.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.WebHooks.Receivers.Custom/1.2.0-rc2

Have fun!